# Image Wrapper CSS

Tags: css

I have this css :

```css
.profile-pic-wrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 84px;
    height: 84px;
    background: linear-gradient(-179deg, #F4F4F4 0%, #C0C0C0 100%);
    border-radius: 140px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22), 0 10px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.34), inset 0 18px 18px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.35), inset 0 -18px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
  }
```

I want to build an image wrapper, a div class where I can insert my image inside.

What I have to add to this class or to the image style to fit this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the gradient a slightly transparent then add an image below it:

```css
.box{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 84px;
    height: 84px;
    background: 
      linear-gradient(-179deg, rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.5) 0%, rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5) 100%),
      url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1069) center/cover;
    border-radius: 140px;
    box-shadow: 
     0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22), 
     0 10px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.34), 
     inset 0 18px 18px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.35), 
     inset 0 -18px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
  }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

And you can rely on CSS variable to easily adjust the image:

```css
.box{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 84px;
    height: 84px;
    background: 
      linear-gradient(-179deg, rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.5) 0%, rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.5) 100%),
      var(--img) center/cover;
    border-radius: 140px;
    box-shadow: 
     0 5px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.22), 
     0 10px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.34), 
     inset 0 18px 18px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.35), 
     inset 0 -18px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.10);
  }
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1069)"></div>
```

Comment: There is way to make it as a wrapper to get : <div class="box">https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1069</div> ?